# I'm having a puzzling issue with Notepadd++

Tags: text-editor

I hope I can format this question in a way that makes sense. I've been teaching myself programming for a bit, and I've really liked using Notepadd++ as my text editor. I'm blind, and it's the only text editor I've been able to find that is simple and accessible with my screen reader.
I got a new computer the other day, and I downloaded Notepad++ in its latest version. I selected all of the advanced features in the setup (such as auto-completion, plugins, themes, etc.,) and it worked great the first time I opened it. But after closing the program and opening it again, all of the advanced functionality is gone. Every subsequent time thereafter, the program acts as though I'd downloaded the minimalist version.
I've downloaded both Windows 32, and then Windows 64 (my system is 64.) I've uninstalled and reinstalled this program many times today, and have tried to find any information I could online, but it doesn't seem like this is a very common issue. Does anyone have any ideas?
Alternatively, I'd be willing to try out any simple text editing tool or IDE that you know is accessible with screen readers, and can be controled exclusively with key commands. I've tried Vim, Atom, and Sublime (all terrible for the blind from what I can tell.)
Help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Sublime Text 3](https://www.sublimetext.com/) and my current favorite editor. It's simple yet powerful editor for programmers.

> A sophisticated text editor for code, markup and prose

it support Windows, Linux and macOS and also available in portable version so you can use without installing.